# facing error "cannot open include file iwanim.h"

Tags: 3d, marmalade

I Am following [this tutorial](http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/native/examplesandtutorials/tutorials/animatedcharactertutorial.html) of **Marmalade SDK**, I have followed each step, now when I try to build the project its showing me an error

```
cannot open include file iwanim.h
```

any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

It means that probably you didn't include the `iwanim` subproject in your mkb's subproject section. The best way to work every tutorial of marmalade is to use marmalade's `launchpad` and open the example project from there. The iwanim project can be found in Studio section of the launchpad. It'll include all basic files, `example` subproject and will be ready to run without errors.

Alternatively you can find all those example project in your `$Marmalade_Root/examples`. In my PC it's `C:/Marmalade/6.1/examples`. Never used marmalade on my mac.